# dateformat with ISO8601 standard

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to convert dateformat `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmm` to `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` with no miliseconds in XML
For now my format is:  `2013-06-21T12:50:01.444`.

I want it in sql server without miliseconds

Comment: What database system are you using? Date formatting functions vary between them (as does XML support). And you could do with adding more description - I'm not actually sure what your start- and end-points actually are. I think one of them is XML (not sure which), what's the other? A column? A variable? A result set?

Comment: are you want to achieve this from sql server? you want the query?

Comment: Search for "regex replace" (assuming the XML is just text): `\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d\:\d\d\.\d\d\d` or a variant thereof `[0-9]{4}` (for year). Oracle has REGEXP_REPLACE.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- Truncate datetime value to seconds in XML variable 
declare @XML xml

-- Create XML
select @XML =
  (
  select getdate() as value
  for xml path(''), type
  )

-- Show current value
select @XML

-- Remove three last characters using substring
set @XML.modify('replace value of (/value/text())[1] 
                 with substring((/value)[1], 1, 19)')

-- Show modified value
select @XML
```

[replace value of (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx)
[substring Function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178063.aspx)

If you don't want to modify your XML but only truncate to second when fetching values you can specify `char(19)` as the SQLType when you use the `value()` method.

```sql
select @XML.value('(/value/text())[1]', 'char(19)')
```

or `datetime2(0)` if you are on SQL Server 2008 or later.

```sql
select @XML.value('(/value/text())[1]', 'datetime2(0)')
```

[value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)
[datetime2 (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)